# Dynamic "use" to PHP anonymous function

Tags: php, anonymous-function

In PHP there is a function called [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), which takes an array, and transforms your data into PHP variables. This function is very useful when I need to send variables to an include. Ex.

```
    extract(array( "test" => 123 ));
    require "test.php"
```

So **test.php**: `print($test);`
**Returns**: `123`

I need to do the same with functions (which I may not know). PHP 5.4 has support for `use` ([Anonymous Function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)), which is quite interesting. Ex.

```
$test = 123;
call_user_func(function() use($test) {
    print($test);
});
```

However, I need to pass variables with other names and amounts. **Something like**:

```
$useArgs = array( "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3 );
call_user_func(function() use(extract($useArgs)) {
    print($a);
    print($b);
    print($c);

    if(isset($d)) {
        print($d);
    }
});
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `extract()` from inside your function

```
$useArgs = array( "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3 );
call_user_func(function() use($useArgs) {
    extract($useArgs);
    print($a);
    print($b);
    print($c);

    if(isset($d)) {
        print($d);
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't you still need to declare `$useArgs` as `global`?

Comment: No, why would you need that? Why would you use `use` if you also had to use `global`? The idea of `use` is to bind a global variable to your anonymous function's scope.

Comment: @kba +1. to be accurate, it binds a variable from the calling scope (global here is a bit ambiguous)